# Creating multiple interfaces for handling different API operations Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I'm creating a REST API in Spring Boot and there are the following tables on the DB:

```
CREATE TABLE Question
(
    id              SERIAL,
    id_survey       INT,
    description     VARCHAR(1000)
    * Other fields *
);

CREATE TABLE QuestionChoice
(
    id          SERIAL,
    id_question INT,
    description VARCHAR(1000)
    * Other fields *
);
```

I have created their respective models, however I need something more flexible for handling different operations, for instance:

1. Returning just a `Question`
2. Returning a `Question` with a list of its `QuestionChoices`
3. Creating a `Question`, not sending in the POST call its `id`, along with a list of its `QuestionChoices` missing the `id_question` field, since all of the relations will be linked after the call

So far I've been using the `Question` model for the first task. For the second and third, I don't know what should I do.

What practices are the best for handling situations such as this?

Comment: why not use a DTO for all data access?

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen do you have any sources I could lookup to?

Comment: How are you communicating with the Database? Are you using JPA repositories? Would also be good if you could add your existing models you have created to the question as well

Comment: @EthanConrad yes, I'm using JPA repositories, there are a few DTOs for some requests. However, I don't know how to handle a request to build something more "complex", since the task two would require two queries (one for the Question and other for its QuestionChoices)

Comment: As suggestion. Think about using GraphQL to manipulate your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use different data objects for data persistence to the database, from the request object that the API uses.

e.g.

```
public class Question {
    private Long id;
    private Integer idSurvey;
    private String description;
}
```

for the database and

```
public class QuestionRequest {
    private Integer idSurvey;
    private String description;
    // plus choices
}
```

Then you write a Service class that expects the `QuestionRequest`, validates the data and creates `Question` and `QuestionChoices` and persists these in the database.

You can follow the same idea when return data from the API - query the database and then populate some `Response` object that holds different fields.

---

2. to handle the two database tables, and whether to query one table or both... this is a big topic.  Go look up "Spring Hibernate JPA, one-to-many mapping" - there are many books and tutorials, e.g. https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-one-to-many-mapping

Answer (score 0):

1. define the DTO
2. use JPA to write select&&insert logic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).